# IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().AvailableFreeSpace is wrong?

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, windows-phone-7.1

I have recently come across a problem downloading large amounts of data to isolated storage on a WP7 device, when significant amounts of free space are lost during download.

More specifically, I check the free space before downloading and it is, let's say, 1.8 GB; then I start downloading and when I get to about 1.1 GB I get a low disk space warning popup, and soon thereafter writing to disk fails with an IOException.

So something is taking up about 700 MB of space on my device (HTC Mozart 7). This value seems consistent through all my tests.

Also, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().AvailableFreeSpace returns close to zero after the IOException is raised, so it's clearly the case of storage being full.

Any additional information/tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you compared the value with what Zune tells you?

Comment: I have found Zune to be highly inaccurate when it comes to this - compared to the settings>about screen on the phone and the AvailableFreeSpace API property, which both give the same value, zune is off by up to 600 MB.

Comment: The extra data does not come from files in the app folder.
After many tests and checks, i have come to the conclusion that those ~700 MB are most probably used by the system-wide HTTP cache. Have any of you observed this same behavior on your devices? Most importantly, assuming that this cannot be disabled, does anyone know the exact value, so I can write some preventive measures into mydownload routine?

Comment: Sounds plausible. Lets try get some focus on this issue.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen - The bounty on this question expired five hours ago, the grace period ends in 19 hours. Did you find any answers appropriate? Quite aside from the bounty, I'd be curious to know I my answer solves your problem.

Comment: Been in Ukraine for the weekend. Anyway, it's @vlad.strugaru who should be able to provide more info.

Comment: Pardon my mistake, Claus. I was hanging out with a former Ukranian pop star a little bit this weekend, if that counts. @vlad.strugaru, I should have directed my previous comment to you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HttpWebRequest to download the files? If so, please try setting the [HttpWebRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowreadstreambuffering%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property to false. The default is true.

You should read the Remarks section of the documentation for that property to see if setting this to false matches your application's needs, since it affects when callbacks occur.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely caching grabbing disk space. For shifting such large amounts of data you should be looking at a protocol other than HTTP, after all it was originally only intended for web page download. I personally would be looking at ftp, otherwise you'll have to look into splitting your data into more manageable chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I feel its failing because you have crossed the threshold limit you might have set for your device in zune. Please refer the screenshot below. If that is whats happening recheck that value and try again. Also note that even after setting it 0% the phone still reserves about 300-500MB 
 
[image]